# How to correctly use @ContainedIn annotation in Hibernate Search?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, hibernate-search

I'm using Hibernate with PostgreSQL
and Hibernate Search (`5.7.0.Alpha1`)
with ElasticSearch (`2.4.2`).

I have two classes: `Book` and `Author`.
A book can have many authors
and an author can author more than one book.

I annotated `Book` class like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.*;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.*;

@Indexed
@Entity
public class Book implements Record {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    protected Long id;

    @Field
    protected String title;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "books_authors",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "author_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    @IndexedEmbedded(includeEmbeddedObjectId = true)
    protected List<Author> authors = new ArrayList<>();

    //constructors, getters and setters
    //...
}
```

The problem is that when an author gets updated
(for example their name changes), the document of the correspoding book
does not change in ElasticSearch.

For example after executing this code:

```
package com.example.app;

import com.example.app.model.Author;
import com.example.app.model.Book;
import com.example.app.model.Category;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class App
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure()
            .buildSessionFactory();

        Author author01 = new Author("Author 01");
        Book book01 = new Book("Book 01");
        book01.addAuthor(author01);

        {
            Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();

            session.save(author01);
            session.save(book01);

            session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.close();
        }

        author01.setName("Author 02");

        {
            Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();

            session.saveOrUpdate(author01);

            session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.close();
        }

        //without this the app won't end
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

the author document in ElasticSearch will get updated,
but the book document will not change:

```
{"_index":"com.example.app.model.author","_type":"com.example.app.model.Author","_id":"2","_score":1,
"_source":{"name":"Author 02"}}
{"_index":"com.example.app.model.book","_type":"com.example.app.model.Book","_id":"3","_score":1,
"_source":{"title":"Elementy","authors":[{"name":"Author 01", "id":"2"}]}}}
```

I read that for the situations like this I need to use `@ContainedIn` annotation at the `Author` side,
so I did. For this reason I needed to add the property `authoredBooks`, I didn't plan it before.

```
package com.example.app.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.*;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.*;

@Indexed
@Entity
public class Author {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    protected long id;

    @Field
    protected String name;

    @ContainedIn
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authors")
    private List<Book> authoredBooks = new ArrayList<>();

    //constructors, getters and setters
    //...
}
```

This however did not change the behaviour of Hibernate Search,
so book document is still not updated.
Could you give some hints on what can I do or check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm using Hibernate with PostgreSQL and Hibernate Search (5.7.0.Alpha1) with ElasticSearch (2.4.2).

First thing to do would be to upgrade to an actual release of Hibernate Search (not an Alpha or Beta), to be sure you're not experiencing a bug that has been solved since.

Apart from that... your initial code only updates one side of the relationship; did you make sure to add a `author01.addBook(book01)` line after `ook01.addAuthor(author01)`?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it solved my problem. Instead of issuing `author01.addBook(book01)` I forced the update of the `author01` object from database (I also added `cascade` and `fetch` annotations), because I think it's a more realistic setup in my case. After the update `author01` contained the `book01` on its list and then `@ContainedIn` worked - the book document got updated in ElasticSearch. Thanks!

Comment: @nuoritoveri - In your question you write that "For this reason I needed to add the property authoredBooks". Did Yoann Rodière's fix work as a standalone solution, or is the property you mention plus the ContainedIn annotation also a critical part of the solution?

Comment: I had to add `authoredBooks` with `@ContainedIn` and then trigger update of the object, so both elements were necessary.